# Modify FirefoxDriver auto scroll to element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am working with a page that has a small frame at the top, this causes issues when firefoxdriver tries to scroll to the element, as firefoxdriver almost always scrolls in a way that put the element at the most top part of the page. When Firefox scrolls to the element, it scrolls in a way that the element would be under the frame, which makes clicking on the element not possible.

Is there anyway to tell firefoxdrive not to scroll the element all the way at the top of the page? Or any other reliable way around this?

Comment: Java? Ruby? Which framework?

Comment: java, I'll put the tag in now

Comment: It sounds like the scroll bar is not scrollbar of web browser. You may need to use JSExecutor to set `element.scrollTop` to scroll up/down.

Comment: @Buaban it scrolls the webpage bar, but I don't want it to scroll the element all the way to the top. There is something that goes over the top of the page,

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run this?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.<your locator here>);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element
);
```

Comment: Also, what versions of firefox and webdriver?  Specific WebDriver versions support a limited range of firefox versions; you have to match them.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 45, I tried your code. It scrolls it to the absolute top, which is under another frame or layover.

Comment: And Selenium Java 2.53? Ok. Please post your HTML.  What element locator are you using in your scroll?

Comment: Yes Selenium Java 2.53. I am using the xpath element locator. Unfortunately I can't post the HTML code.